# how to select all cells in tableview using custom button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, core-animation, grayscale

I have a tableView in which all cells contain an imageView.

By clicking on imageView it will apply grayscale to it.

I want to select all rows using bar button item.

How to achieve this can anyone help me.

This is the code I'm applying for images to make black and white.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cellLabelSelected.text = "Card Number \(indexPath.row) Selected "
    print(" selected \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! 
    SecondTableViewCell

    guard let currentCGImage = images!.cgImage else { return }

        let currentCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: currentCGImage)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome")

        filter?.setValue(currentCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")

        filter?.setValue(CIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6), 
        forKey: "inputColor")

        filter?.setValue(1.0, forKey: "inputIntensity")

        guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else { return }

        let context = CIContext()

        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            print(processedImage.size)
            cell.cellImage.image = processedImage
    }

}     

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
     cell.cellImage.image = images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method on barButtonItem clicked:

```
func selectAllRows() {
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that nothing changes @Arash

Comment: that's because you are implementing `didDeselect`, when one cell selected the others deselected as well

Comment: But it doesn't change the filter to images, i have remove deselect func. When i tap bar button item it should apply filter to all the cell images.

Comment: I can't figure out what is your question exactly! you have problem in selecting cell or applying filter to images ?

Comment: as you can see in my code when i tap on image it apply filter i have did that in didSelectRowAt. Now by tapping on bar button filter should apply on all the cells.

Comment: Did you set outlet for your tableView?

Comment: Yes i have set outlet for tableview